# Issue with apache Tika Extraction for Tabular Column Data in PDF

Tags: extract, apache-tika, tika-server

I extracted a PDF that has tabular column data using apache Tika, in the result the row data from different columns are getting merged

Before Extracting
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | saikiran |
| 2        | pavan    |

The above Tabular column data is what i am trying to extract

After Extracting the below is the result

saikiran1
pavan2

I am expecting the result to be like i have mentioned down below
1 saikiran 2 pavan

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TikaExtraction {
 
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {

      //Assume sample.txt is in your current directory          
      File file = new File("sample.txt");
      
      
      Tika tika = new Tika();
      String filecontent = tika.parseToString(file);
      System.out.println("Extracted Content: " + filecontent);
   }   
}